# skipping data in php foreach if the data is empty fails

Tags: php

I would like to skip the empty data in a php foreach loop.

I have the following data structure:

```
$sales = array(
  0=>array(
    0=>array({cash_saleno:null, test:1, val:3}) //the data is an object 
         1=>array({cash_saleno:ABCD, test:23, val:4})
         2=>array({cash_saleno:ABCD, test:23, val:4})
      ),
    1=>array()...//structure as above
  )
)
```

Now I would like to skip the index 0 since the `cash_Sale_no` is `null`, so I have tried:

```
    foreach ($exportedatas as $key => $exportedata) {
       foreach ($exportedata as $exportedatum) {
          if (!empty($exportedatum->cash_Saleno)) {
               ...proceed with saving the data
          }
       }
    }
```

But the above doesnt save the data, but when I remove the `if (!empty($exportedatum->cash_Saleno))` check, it works but it now saves even the null columns. How do I correct the above problem?

Comment: In the data structure the field is called `cash_saleno` and in the code it's `cash_Saleno`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need one more nested loop to access `cash_saleno`. The following code worked for me:

```
$sales = array(
  0=>array(
    0=>array(
      0=>array('{"cash_saleno": null, "test": 1, "val": 3}'), //the data is an object
      1=>array('{"cash_saleno": "ABCD", "test": 23, "val": 4}'),
      2=>array('{"cash_saleno": "ABCD", "test": 23, "val": 4}'),
    ),
  )
);

foreach ($sales as $key => $exportedata) {
  foreach ($exportedata as $exportedatum) {
    foreach ($exportedatum as $data) {
      $obj = json_decode($data[0]);
      if (!empty($obj->{'cash_saleno'})) {
        // Save data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what about when its an object how do you check

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI I've updated my code so that the innermost data is a json object.

Comment: BTW, if the innermost array is just going to have 1 element (the json object), it would be better to get rid of that innermost array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your errorlog?

$exportedatum is a array containing the object, so you should test:  if(!empty($exportedatum[0]->cash_Saleno)) ...